# Efficiently bind different keys to the same command

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

I'm developing a Prolog REPL plugin for SublimeText2. Like the prolog interpreter itself I want to offer multiple different keybindings for the same actions; e.g. one can use both `;` and `n` to dismiss a solution presented by the repl. Currently, to achieve this I just duplicate the keybinding:

```
{ "keys": [";"], "command": "mycmd", "args": {},
"context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.some_setting", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "replmode_p"}
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["n"], "command": "mycmd", (etc ...) }
```

This blows up the size of the keybindings file considerably as many of the definitions are rather large because they only apply to specific contexts. Is there a way to do this without duplicating the bindings, or anything else I can do to optimize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick browse through `Preferences->Key Bindings-Default` shows multiple entries for the same commands, for example

```json
{ "keys": ["backspace"], "command": "left_delete" },
{ "keys": ["shift+backspace"], "command": "left_delete" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+backspace"], "command": "left_delete" },
```

and

```json
{ "keys": ["shift+delete"], "command": "cut" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+insert"], "command": "copy" },
{ "keys": ["shift+insert"], "command": "paste" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+x"], "command": "cut" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+;"], "command": "cut" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+c"], "command": "copy" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+v"], "command": "paste" },
```

just in the first 40 lines (on Windows), so unfortunately I think the answer is no. The only way I could think of doing it,

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+d"], "command": "find_under_expand_skip" },
```

maps a double key sequence to the action - hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> runs the command.

Sorry!